# Redirect to dynamically generated html in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I am building an SPA with **Angular 5** and I'm calling an authentication and authorization service.
This service checks if I have a session active and if there's no session or if it has expired then returns 401 **and an HTML with the company-wide login page**. 
I built a service for making this call, like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private authServicePath = '/<path-to-the-service>';
    private authToken: string;
    private serviceURL: string;
    private requestOptions: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

    validateAuth() {
        this.serviceURL = environment.endpoint + this.authServicePath;
        this.authToken = this.cookieService.get('SESSION-TOKEN-COOKIE');
        this.requestOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders(
                {
                    'SESSION-TOKEN-COOKIE': this.authToken
                }
            )
        };

        return this
                .http
                .get(this.serviceURL, this.requestOptions)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        // Do nothing
                    },
                    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        /*window.document.write = err.error;
                        window.document.close();*/
                    }
                );
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm calling the service. If the token is valid then there's nothing to do, but if I don't have any active/valid session, then the service will return the 401 Unauthorized and in its payload (`.error` field) I will get something like this:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="..." ...
```

How do I tell my app to redirect me to this generated page?

As you can see, I tried writing a new HTML with `window.document.write` but it didn't work.
I understand that Angular Router can only redirect to components belonging to the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, I found a way to do this. It looks very *hackish* to me, but it is the first step.
If someone has any advice on this, please let me know.

I used Javascript *the old way* to append the content of the generated HTML to the `<body>` tag of my app. Since the HTML contains **an unnamed form**, I've done this:

```
(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        if (err.status === 401){
                            document.body.innerHTML = err.error;
                            let form = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
                            form.submit();
                        }
                    }
```

It looks ugly to me, but it is the best that I can get at this time. If someone has another approach to this, please let me know. 
I'll mark this question as answered and if there is a better answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right answer.

Thanks

Comment: Since you have to handle an entire html file, I cant think of a better way to do it. I agree with your reservations - but it'll work...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you should be doing is redirecting to an error/login page or displaying an error message with *partial* page content populated from your service (not the *whole* html page).

If you want to go that route, just set a property to contain your HTML and then bind it to the InnerHTML of a div element as follows:

**typescript**

`public myHtmlCode: string = '<b>header</b><p>paragraph</p>';`

**template**

`<div [innerHTML]="myHtmlCode"></div>`

Comment: No, unfortunately, the page returned by the service is the whole page that I have to display, so I can't _embed_ it into my app, but instead I have to use that HTML (that is a login page). It is not static, because in that HTML there are some pre-filled fields with information about my login request.

Comment: @AlejandroEcheverri I see - in that case I think you'll have to look at using an iframe.

Comment: I found a way _that I don't like because it looks hackish_. If you have any comments please let me know.